# When I copy a list and delete an element, why does this delete from the original too?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

suppose I have a list:
x=[1,2,3]

I want to make a copy of it:
y=x

I want to delete the first element from y:
del y[0]

Now y only has 2 elements:
[2,3]

***BUT***

x also has 2 elements too!!

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> x=[1,2,3]
>>> y=x
>>> del y[0]
>>> x
[2, 3]
>>> y
[2, 3]
>>>
```

Why is this? And how do i delete elements from y without effecting x?

Comment: Is it a duplicate if the answer to two questions are same, but the two questions are different?

Comment: @ivand58 no, *there was no copy at all*. Any copy would do in this case, shallow or deep. `y=x` is not a copy in Python, it is assignment, and assignment doesn't copy.

Comment: @Abhishek there are certain types of questions that appear so frequently that they have sort of settled on canonical duplicates among the community, even if they aren't exact duplicates.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Okay! Just wanted to know. I'm sort of new here too

Comment: @Abhishek no problem. It's definitely a judgement call. That's why people can vote on duplicates and vote on re-opening. It's a team effort around here.